# t-sql table join

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there any way I can do a join between two tables where the resulting table has only the columns of the left table without the need to discriminate all the columns names in the select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Select LeftTable.*
From LeftTable
    Inner Join RightTable
        On LeftTable.Id = RightTable.Id
```

Comment: This works, but be aware that if this query is part of a view, any new columns added to LeftTable will not be selected by the view until the view is recompiled. (at least I've observed this behavior in MS SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Select T.* from tbl1 T, tbl2 J

Comment: `Select T.* from tbl1 T, tbl2 J` does not look like a join. It is a Cartesian product.

Comment: I've just showed the T.* and ignore the rest of the statement, as it should been enough to understand :-)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
Select t1.id, t1.name, t1.age FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.Something = Something
```